# Series of positive-definite kernels

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose I have a positive definite, shift invariant kernel $k_1(x-y)=k_1(\delta)$. I want to know whether the sum (where $a_n\geq 0$) 
$$
k(\delta) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n k_1(n\delta)\tag{*}
$$
is also positive definite. The partial sum 
$$
k_m(\delta) = \sum_{n=1}^{m} a_n k_1(n\delta)
$$
is obviously positive definite. I suspect that I'm making things too difficult for myself, but I can't seem to figure out how to extend the positive definite notion to an infinite sum. I suspect that I need to invoke Fatou's Lemma, but it's eluding me.

Under what conditions on $a_n$ is $k_\infty$ positive definite, and what lemmas/theorems would I need to invoke to prove it? Caveat -- this would have to extend to kernels on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out not to be that difficult.

Assume that $k$ isn't positive definite. Then there has to be some collection of points whose corresponding Gram matrix is indefinite (since the diagonal has to be nonnegative, it can't be negative definite). Then there is a $y$ such that $y^TKy <0$. But the Gram matrices for the partial kernels can't have this property, since they're positive definite. The sequence $\{y^TK_my\}_m$ then has to be nonnegative and nondecreasing (since the $a_n$ are nonnegative), and this is a contradiction.

EDIT: You **do** need the MCT to show convergence.